# Docker compose and and pipeline in azure devops not rendering variable in dockerfile COPY statement properly

Tags: docker-compose, azure-pipelines

Copy statement in dockerfile is blank when using env variable from pipeline like {testvar}

the variable resolves correctly in the command as below:

`testvar=/myfilepath/ docker compose -f $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myfolder dockercomposetest/docker-compose.yml up --build`

(Truncated pipeline code below)

```
         parameters:
         - name: filelocation
           displayName: file-location

         variables:
         - name: filelocation
          value: ${{ parameters.filelocation }}

         stages: 
           etc...
           - checkout git://$(filelocation)
           - script: echo $(fileapilocation)
           - testvar=$(fileapilocation) docker compose -f docker- 
             compose.yml up --build
```

(I have also tried the above by declaring the testvar explicitly as a env var with the ##vso[task...] syntax)

(Truncated compose file)

```
    alpine2:
      build:
        context: ./python2
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.python2
      container_name: test-container2
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
        ls -ll "/some/testfolder"
```

(I have also tried the above with
environment:
`testvar: ${testvar}`

Docker file:

```
    FROM python:3-alpine
    WORKDIR /some/testfolder
    COPY ${testvar} /some/testfolder
```

Output:

I can see in layer 3 of the docker build that the COPY variable is not being populated as I would like -

```
    #7 [alpine2 3/3] COPY  /usr/src/app/
    #7 DONE 0.0s
```

Summary - the testvar is correctly populated in the docker command output by the pipeline, but the testvar is not carried into the Dockerfile for action.

Hopefully the code above is laid out ok on submission, I have typed it out so possible there might be a typo, but I hope its enough to get some help - I think its just something wrong with my notation for the testvar is all?

Frustratingly, I can make similar to this work locally, just not in devops. I am already using docker compose elsehwere in devops, but this is the first time I have had to do the above.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to pass the pipeline variable value to the dockerfile when running docker composer.

To meet your requirement, you can refer to the following steps to modify the files in your docker composer project.

Step1: Add the **args** parameter in the compose file to pass the variable value to the dockerfile.

For example:

```
alpine2:
  build:
    context: ./python2
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.python2
    args:
      testvar: ${filelocation}
  container_name: test-container2
  command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
    ls -ll "/some/testfolder"
```

Step2: Set the **ARG** field to get the value pass from compose file.

For example:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
ARG testvar
WORKDIR /some/testfolder
COPY ${testvar} /some/testfolder
```

Step3: Pass the variable in the Pipeline task.

For example:

```
steps:
- script: 'filelocation=$(filelocation) docker-compose up'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. your answer certainly looks solid, but I am struggling to get it to run. I can see the variable is correctly reported into the compose pipeline call but I still get that blank in the actual copy statement. I think this is one of those "works for me" moments. Would you be kind enough to post the full example code so I can play spot the difference with mine? cheers.

Comment: @phil_99 The code sample in my answer is changed based on your demo in the question. You can directly check it with your files. I think that you can find the changes between the files. Feel free to let me know if it can work.

Comment: On the other hand,  in your original demo, you can pass the filelocation  variable value to the command line, but it should not be passed to the composer file and dockerfile file. Therefore, you need to refer to my answer to update the composer file and dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks! I had some incorrect notation and for my ease I moved the dockerfile inline. All good :)